# Django - Difference between admin save_model() and post_save signal

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

For my application I need to do extra operations when a model is saved via form. In practice, I need to add a value in another model if certain conditions are present in the form.

To do this I have two options, but I want to understand the pros and cons of both.

1. Use the post_save signal
2. Overwrite the save_model method in admin.py, since it is said in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) that "Overriding this method allows doing pre- or post-save operations."

I currently use the latter in this way

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

    #some pre save operations....

    #this call the save model method
    super(MyModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    #some post save operations...
```

and it works

But what I want to understand is:

1. For what I must do, what are the differences between the two approaches and what is the most correct.
2. Is the save_model method related to the use of the admin interface? What happens if I use another frontend different from Django's admin?
3. In general, what is the difference between doing pre and post save operations overwriting save_model and using signals?

Comment: The way i see it, a model object could be saved from anywhere inside your app, not just django admin. Only way to make sure something happens every time an object is saved is to use pre/post_save signals or override <Model>.save() method. After that all you have to do is watch out for bulk updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you got it right. And this might help you to understand the difference.

`save_model` method from `ModelAdmin` called when you are trying to create or update something from **django admin only** but signals are triggered **regardless** of place where actions happened. Which means `pre` or `post` operations in `save_model` method won't work if you change model from somewhere outside of **django admin** but **signals** will work for both from outside of admin views and from your custom written code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

If possible i would prefer to add signals over overwriting the save_model. Signals allow certain senders to notify a set of receivers that some action has taken place. They're especially useful when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events. Also it is like [event driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) paradigm. That helps to make code organize and clean.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take a rather regular example of the process. We want to register a new user and we also have created a profile model that we want a user's profile saved only when valid User information is saved.

We can create a new User in the Django's admin and use the `saved_model` method in the `ModelAdmin` to save other parts of the form to the `Profile` model. This is the "normal" way of doing it. But using this way, you can only access the User and the Profile from the Django Admin panel. A "User Registration" form **outside** of the Django Admin would **not** work since the User would have to be registered to access Django Admin controls.

But using the `post_save` signal, a new User and Profile can be created and updated whether you use the Django Admin panel or a custom form that saves to the `User` and `Profile` models.

Therefore using signals is the most flexible but you will now have to make sure you have a way of validating the information coming from the custom form.